# On a VPS Server, is there a shared location, accessible to multiple domains?

Tags: php, cpanel, vps, shared, whm

I've recently purchased a VPS running Centos and cPanel.

I have several domains setup, all with their own individual cPanels. However, I'd like for the websites to be able to access a private, shared folder on the server.

I've written PHP classes that I'd like all the sites to have access to and I don't want to have to upload the files multiple times for individual sites.

Is there a folder where cPanel 1 and cPanel 2 can access whilst existing on the same server? Or could I create one?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The cPanel environment is designed to host websites within individual accounts while keeping their content separate and secure from other cPanel accounts on the same server.   While you can configure your server to allow this type of sharing,  doing so is not officially supported by cPanel as it circumvents many functions specific to the type of environment cPanel is trying to create.

http://serversitters.com/share-a-folder-between-2-cpanel-accounts-on-a-server.html